# How to interact a form with tabindex = -1 using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, automation

So there is a login form with "tabindex = -1" and I can't reach its elements and I think that's the reason. I have another similar form in which the form is a part of the page's body and I can interact with its elements.

Is there any way to interact with the form using selenium with tabindex = -1?

Comment: post url and what you try to archive

Comment: https://www.opelforum.net is the url. You should click on the green button "Kayıt Ol" on the top right for the registration form. I want to interact with the first text bar named "Kullanıcı adı".

Answer (score 0):

This css selector can help:

```
.overlay form.block .block-body>.formRow.formRow--input:nth-of-type(2) label
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to open registration window, wait for window to load and send keys into input fields:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os
import time

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path =os.path.abspath(os.getcwd()) + "/chromedriver")
browser.get("https://www.opelforum.net/")

# click register button
register = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="header"]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/a[2]')
register.click()
time.sleep(2)

# send keys into username
username = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[5]/div/div[2]/form/div/div/dl[2]/dd/input')
username.send_keys('username')
```